# Error : when i import Image lib, i can not use Image() Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I import image lib, i can not use Image().

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
Center(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image()
```

Here ist Error "Image isnt a function "

Also i update pubspec.yaml

```
 dependencies:


 image: ^3.1.3
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When two libraries conflict, you have to give one of them an alias and use it like

```
alias.method()
```

. For example:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLibrary;
Center(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: imageLibrary.Image()
```